# how to separate list in python?

Tags: python, list, token

```
fruit,apple
fruit,tomato
vegetable,carrot
fruit,pear
vegetable,celery
vegetable,cabbage
vegetable,cauliflower
fruit,banana
```

I want to separate list from fruit and vegetable  like this

fruit

```
apple 
tomato 
pear 
banana
```

Vegetable

```
carrot
celery
cabbage
cauliflower
```

this is my code that i did so far

```
infile = open("hw16.txt","r")
lines = infile.readlines()
infile.close()

print lines
x = []
y = []
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    tokens = lines[i].rstrip('\n').split(",")
    x.append(str(tokens[0]))
    y.append(str(tokens[1]))
print  x
print y
```

thank you

Comment: Please format your code properly. Do not use html to format it. Copy and paste your code from your editor, highlight it all, then hit the {} button.

Comment: What is your question? What is the output your code produces?

Comment: I want to separate list from fruit and vegetable like this

fruit

apple 
tomato 
pear 
banana
Vegetable

carrot
celery
cabbage
cauliflower

Comment: i'm sorry i try to learn how to post also

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answers

```
mydict = {'fruit' : [], 'vegetable' : []}

for line in file:   
    key, val = line.rstrip().split(',')     
    mydict[key].append(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vegetables = []
fruits = []

for line in file:
    type , name = line.strip().split(',') 
    if type == 'fruit':
        fruits.append(name)
    else:
        vegetables.append(name)
```

Output:

```
In [87]: print vegetables
['carrot', 'celery', 'cabbage', 'cauliflower']

In [88]: print fruits
['apple', 'tomato', 'pear', 'banana']
```

Comment: You're right, but it's just a solution for her 2 different types as she stated